# How can I know what is the process name who make my HDD work intensivly?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1

My computer is very very optimized for speed.

Complete control with Autoruns  , complete control on task scheduler, no Maleware , no Trojans ,no idle scans from AntiVirus ( eset nod) , used to use HijackThis , but since it doesn't work with 64 bit , moved to HiJackFree. No unused services(services.msc) are on : most of them on manual/disable. ( no indexing services etc... due to SSD).

But sometimes I look at the computer HDD and I see the led ON for about 10 seconds which means HDD is working without any special reason. ( and it's not a dump to pagefile/hibernation file since they are both OFF).

**Question**

How can I know what is the process name that is doing this ? I tried FileMon but there is too many data there and there is no grouping to know peeks of hdd usage.

Edit:

I already tried Task manager with IO column added but it doesn't show me the picks at time interval. it shows the AVG/COUNT but there is no *burst* information which I can suspect.

Comment: You could use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Sort the processes according to their input/output rate. Process Explorer also provides a graphical display which might provide hints when and how long excessive HDD access occurs.

Comment: No need for 3rd party tools, Task Manager provides this basic functionality. Have you tried it?

Comment: As previous comment said, you should try [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), I use it myself, it's very useful. [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is a good alternative too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileMon is obsolete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx). You should use [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) instead.

[Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) allows you to slice and dice the data far more easily than FileMon did and if that is not sufficient, you can always export as a CSV and start hacking at it in Excel.

That said, it's probably superfetch or seach indexing kicking in wich is *a good thing*

Comment: Comments also  suggest Process explorer , what is the difference ?

Comment: Process Explorer is a Taskmanager on steroids, very good but it's realtime. Although you have a history graph as to a processes IO, it will not show you what files/folders are being used. Procmon does. It would be my preferred tool for this scenario.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Did you find the culprit?

Comment: No I haven't set it yet. I'm at work. and I need to set it and leave it to work for a half a day. Will update.